# is it possible to make mouse over function for all button? (in only one function)

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a problem with mouse over function

this is an example (not the problem):

```
def on_enter(e):
    navi_frame.place(x=0, y=0)

def on_leave(e):
    navi_frame.place(x=-200, y=0)

#navigation frame on left side
navi_frame = Frame(root, bg="black", width=250, height=1200)
navi_frame.place(x=0, y=0)
navi_frame.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
navi_frame.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
```

this works well, but i have a lot of buttons. my problem is that i write for each button (or frame) a new function. i tried different things to make only ONE function for all buttons... but all things with if statments etc. don't work (which i tried). i dont find any guide for this, so i want to ask you guys.. . or is it impossible and i need to write for each button a new function?

Comment: You can bind same function to all buttons and use `event.widget` to reference the button that triggers the event function.

Comment: navi_frame = Frame(root, bg="black", width=250, height=1200, event.widget)
navi_frame.place(x=0, y=0) ? it doesnt work

Comment: It is used in the event callbacks: `def on_enter(e): e.widget.place(x=0, y=0)` and `def on_leave(e): e.widget.place(x=-200, y=0)`.

Comment: oh wow... thx a lot. works very well now

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do it by Making A List of All Buttons and Then using for loop . As Given Below

```
b=[Button(r, text=x) for x in range(10)]
```

And then

```
for x in range(10):
    b[x].bind("<Button>" , lambda event,i=x:fun(i))
```

Where fun is a Function taking integer as input

```
def fun(ButtonNumber):
    print(ButtonNumber)
```

Comment: i have already a list. but my question was, is it possible to make ONE function for all buttons (or a few of them). because the list ist too long.

Comment: There is Already ONE Function given "fun(ButtonNumber)"  ,you can check ButtonNumber according to your need.Or if you want to call a function for every Buttons, you can add "command=functionName" inside the Button . e.g. Button (root, text='Btn' , command=functionName)